# DAX Subtotal PowerBI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, subtotal

`I need to create a measure having the SUM of the column "Sales" each time a value in the row "Month" appears.`
`e.g. In a row I have this two values:
Sales= 500
Month= April

I need a measure to get the SUM of the column Sales for every row with April in the column Month, but in that column I have another values like January, February, March, May and so on where I also need to get the subtotals so I guess the Filter I should use has to be "dynamic"

I need to get the sum of Sales per each month to be able to divide Sales per that result to get the representativeness of each line over the SUM per month, this value should be dynamic and change with each filter I apply on the dashboard`

Comment: Your question seems basic or isn't clear. Suggest you rephrase the question with what you have tried and where you are stuck, or otherwise do some research and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correct, you need 2 measure to calculate monthly sales and yearly sales as below-

```
tottal_monthly_sale = SUM(your_table_name[sales])
```

and

```
total_yearly_sale = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[sales]),
    ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[year])
)
```

From the above 2 measures, if you now divide the first one with the second one, you will get the percentage.